# Toast notifications missing application icon when launched from service

Tags: c#, c++, windows-10, toast, msix

*Question:*

Why does my unpackaged C# application show its icon when I launch it but not when my Windows service launches it? How can I make my app's toasts always show the app's icon?

*Details:*

I have a C++ Windows Service that launches a C# Win32 application for toast functionality, since toasts cannot be launched directly from a service to a user. It is an absolute requirement that the service launches the toast app. To my frustration, however, the app's icon (i.e. the icon shown on the .exe in Explorer) refuses to show *only* when launched by my service. Here is an example of what I see when my service launches the app (Note the three squares. This is the Windows 10 default icon):

[image: Toast from app instance launched by my service]

When I manually launch the app (i.e. click it), this is what I see instead:

[image: Toast from app instance I launched]

The only difference between the above two screenshots is the launch method. The most succinct way I can describe my issue is that I want the launch method (launched from a service) that yields the first screenshot to yield the second screenshot instead.

I can provide the code snippet I used to generate these toasts, although I doubt its usefulness for finding a solution:

```
var notifier = ToastNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier();

var xml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<toast><visual><binding template=\"ToastGeneric\"><text>Foo</text<text>Bar</text></binding></visual></toast>");

var notif = new Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification(xml);

notifier.Show(notif);
```

The most useful code sample I believe I can provide is the code that the service uses to launch the app:

```
void SpawnToastApp()
{
    constexpr int       nProcFlags  = DETACHED_PROCESS | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    constexpr wchar_t*  wcsDesktop  = L"WinSta0\\Default";
    constexpr wchar_t*  wcsToastApp = L"ToastApp\\Toast App (WIP).exe";
    HANDLE              hUser       = NULL;
    STARTUPINFOW        si{ 0 };
    wchar_t             wcsCmdLine[MAX_PATH]{ 0 };

    _snwprintf_s(wcsCmdLine, _TRUNCATE, L"\"%S\\%s\" %lu", _strInstallDir, wcsToastApp, GetCurrentProcessId());

    _sessionCanToast = WTSQueryUserToken(_sessionId, &hUser);
    if (_sessionCanToast)
    {
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        si.lpDesktop = wcsDesktop;

        _sessionCanToast = CreateProcessAsUserW(hUser, NULL, wcsCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
            nProcFlags, NULL, NULL,
            &si, &_toastHandlerProcessInformation);
    }
    
    if(!_sessionCanToast)
    {
        /// Log it
    }

    if (hUser) { CloseHandle(hUser); };
}
```

I include the C++ code because I believe that I have narrowed the problem down to the launch method but am unsure the specific cause beyond that.

*Additional Information:*

These screenshots utilize `Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotifications` created from raw XML, but I have also tried using the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` NuGet Package as [recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop#step-1-install-nuget-package) to the same effect.

I believe this project is a Windows Form App.

I am not using any sort of package--no APPX, MSIX, or sparse package. This is meant to be a lightweight app whose sole function is for toasts. While using a package isn't out of the question, suffice it to say that the number of hurdles and implementation issues make packaging this app undesirable. Indeed, the only reason I would want to package this app is for the icon in the upper left-hand corner of it, which it evidently does already, just not in the way I desire.

Similar to but NOT a duplicate of:

- [Change toast notification icon in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647156/change-toast-notification-icon-in-wpf)

  - I have already done this. My issue pertains to the icon's inconsistency rather than the lack of it entirely.
- [Why is app icon missing for toast notifications in action center on desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947267/why-is-app-icon-missing-for-toast-notifications-in-action-center-on-desktop)

  - I am using a Release build of my app
- [Cannot override notification app logo for Windows 10/11 VSTO app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629677/cannot-override-notification-app-logo-for-windows-10-11-vsto-app)

  - Using `AppOverrideLogo` gets my icon to show under all circumstances, but it's more like a picture in the body of the toast rather than the small icon in the upper left-hand corner of the toast. Essentially, it's not the style I want.

EDIT 1:
I followed a sparse packaging guide found [here](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/sparse-package/) to more or less the same result, the main difference being that now no icon not shows up at all anywhere. I used the asset generator in Visual Studio and then used the MSIX unpackaging tool to inspect the contents of the sparse package and confirmed it contained the generated assets. I had to comment out the reference to the splash screen because the app failed to register with that line included in the manifest.

EDIT 2:
I have decided to proceed with this app as if I am not having this issue, and so I used Visual Studio's [Performance Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022#post_mortem) to analyze my app's resources. The Performance Profiler launched my toast app, and the toasts had the correct icon, so at this point I am 100% certain it has something to do with my service's launch method. Unfortunately, I am no closer to understanding why the icon does not show *only* when launched from my service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've experienced a similar issue. I have not come across a way to fix the underlying issue, but I do have a remediation for it.

When your application shows a toast notification an entry is created in `Settings > Notifications & actions` so that the user can choose to disable it. You can find each entry defined in the registry under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppUserModelId\`. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-other-apps) provides a different location in the registry, but I always found them under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

If you find the `AppUserModelId` key for your application, which should be auto-generated in your case, then you'll notice it is missing the `IconUri` value. The quick fix is to do a one-time setup and set the `IconUri` data to the path to your icon (assuming you have it somewhere on disk).

However, this fix leads to another question. How do you determine which `AppUserModelId` is for your notification application if it is auto-generated, so that you can access it in the registry? Iterating over all the registry subkeys is not ideal. It turns out you can manually set the `AppUserModelId` if you use the [SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-setcurrentprocessexplicitappusermodelid). I run this method at the beginning of my application.

Below is a barebones C# implementation.

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
internal static extern void SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string AppID);

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"AppUserModelId\MY_APPUSERMODELID");
  if (key == null) {
    key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"AppUserModelId\MY_APPUSERMODELID");
  }
  if (key.GetValue("IconUri") == null) { 
    key.SetValue("IconUri", "path/to/your/icon");
  }
  // Show toast notification here
}
```

I don't know if it is a full-proof solution, but it worked for me so far.

Comment: A note for future readers: I will be accepting this answer because its resemblance to the solution I implemented is undeniable, but I have not personally tested whether this will work in C#. Please read my answer for the solution I implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76113052/16496799

@Jonah Bui, thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @[Jonah Bui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21693371/jonah-bui)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76075876/16496799), I believe there is a solution to this issue for C# implementations, although I am not 100% sure because I will not be testing it myself. However, the solution he describes perfectly mirrors my own, so I have no doubt it would work.

The solution I ultimately started using was to re-write the app in C++. I recognize this is somewhat of an anti-solution given the question, which is why I elected to accept Jonah's answer instead.

I followed [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop-cpp-wrl) on sending toasts from an unpackaged C++ application, which links to [this github repository](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts). Despite the guide being for WRL, the directory in the repository that was most useful for me was the [WINRT directory](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/tree/master/CPP-WINRT) because shows an implementation that does not use a package for its identity.

Incorporating the `DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.h` and `DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.cpp` allows a C++ application to give itself identity for toast notifications by calling `DesktopNotificationManagerCompat::Register();` at the start of `main()`. Note that using WINRT requires using C++17 for the compiler's (e.g. Visual Studio) language standard. I also seem to remember Windows 10 build 17763 being the minimum version that supports unpackaged apps sending toasts, but I could be misremembering because I cannot find a source for this information.

Here is the `Register()` function:

```
void DesktopNotificationManagerCompat::Register(std::wstring aumid, std::wstring displayName, std::wstring iconPath)
{
    // If has identity
    if (HasIdentity())
    {
        // No need to do anything additional, already registered through manifest
        return;
    }

    _win32Aumid = aumid;

    std::wstring clsidStr = CreateAndRegisterActivator();

    // Register via registry
    std::wstring subKey = LR"(SOFTWARE\Classes\AppUserModelId\)" + _win32Aumid;

    // Set the display name and icon uri
    SetRegistryKeyValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, L"DisplayName", displayName);

    if (!iconPath.empty())
    {
        SetRegistryKeyValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, L"IconUri", iconPath);
    }
    else
    {
        DeleteRegistryKeyValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, L"IconUri");
    }

    // Background color only appears in the settings page, format is
    // hex without leading #, like "FFDDDDDD"
    SetRegistryKeyValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, L"IconBackgroundColor", iconPath);

    SetRegistryKeyValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, L"CustomActivator", L"{" + clsidStr + L"}");
}
```

This function and Jonah's are identical in functionality. In fact, when I looked at the registry key that Jonah pointed to, I found the old AUMIDs from my C# implementation right alongside the AUMID for my current C++ app. None of the C# AUMIDs have an IconUri value, which is almost certainly indicates what the issue was all along. In my code, I would try to set the icon uri, but I never did it directly through the registry.